# Calculating difference of days accounting for weekends and holidays

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to **calculate a difference between days** (example 22.5.1999. + 200 days) **but exclduding weekends** (saturday and sundays) **and holidays** (1.6., 3.7., 9.8. <- made up for the purposes of demonstration)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [WORKDAY function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/workday-HP005209339.aspx):

> WORKDAY(start_date,days,holidays)
>
> Important   Dates should be entered by using the DATE function, or as
>   results of other formulas or functions. For example, use
>   DATE(2008,5,23) for the 23rd day of May, 2008. Problems can occur if
>   dates are entered as text.
>
> **Start_date**     is a date that represents the start date.
>
> **Days     is the number of nonweekend and nonholiday days before or
>   after start_date.** A positive value for days yields a future date; a
>   negative value yields a past date.
>
> **Holidays**     is an optional list of one or more dates to exclude from
>   the working calendar, such as state and federal holidays and floating
>   holidays. The list can be either a range of cells that contain the
>   dates or an array constant of the serial numbers that represent the
>   dates.

`=WORKDAY(A1;B1;A2:A4)` gets the result "**29.02.2000**" for example:

[image]